# Images not displaying in email (shows as .bin)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm creating emails that has to be sent out to technicians. There are about 12 emails (only one will be sent out depending on which printer model was chosen). The emails everything is sending out fine. The only problem I'm having is that the images are not displaying, they are showing as attachments with a .bin extention. I'm using a case statement to send out the emails. Any help on what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is how my code looks like:

In case statement:

```
    string headerPath = Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\EmailImages\\1022_03.png");
            LinkedResource img1022_03 = new LinkedResource(headerPath);
            img1022_03.ContentId = "1022_03";

            string tonerPath = Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\EmailImages\\TonerSignature.png");
            LinkedResource TonerSignature = new LinkedResource(tonerPath);
            TonerSignature.ContentId = "TonerSignature";

            string img1022_11Path = Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\EmailImages\\1022_11.png");
            LinkedResource img1022_11 = new LinkedResource(img1022_11Path);
            img1022_11.ContentId = "1022_11";

            AlternateView avDefault = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(SendOMD(), null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            avDefault.LinkedResources.Add(img1022_03);
            avDefault.LinkedResources.Add(TonerSignature);
            avDefault.LinkedResources.Add(img1022_11);
            Mail.AlternateViews.Add(avDefault);
```

This code is inside a case statement of default. Outside the case I add the smtp details:

```
     System.Configuration.Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/web.config");
        MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
        if (mailSettings != null)
        {
            int port = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Port;
            string host = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
            string password = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.Password;
            string username = mailSettings.Smtp.Network.UserName;
        }
        SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient();
        SMTP.Send(Mail);
```

This is what my email method looks like:

```
    private string SendOMD()
    {
        string techType = radTechnicianType.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string techString = "";

        if (techType == "Field Technician")
            techString = "Please send a technician to replace the toner on the above mentioned machine.";
        else if (techType == "Onsite technician")
            techString = "Please replace the toner on the above mentioned machine.";
        else
            techString = "Please send a technician to replace the toner on the above mentioned machine.";

        StringBuilder stringBuilt = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<style type=""text/css"">");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(".divStyle { font-family:Verdana,sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size:10pt; font-weight: bold; }");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(".par { font-family:Verdana,sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica; font-size:10pt; width:658px; }");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("table { border: 1px solid #000; border-collapse: collapse; font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt; background-color:#dcdcdc; }");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("table td { border-left: 1px solid #000; font-family:Verdana,sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;  font-size:10pt; background-color:snow; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; padding-left:2px; margin-left:2px; padding-right:5px; margin-right:5px; }");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("table td:first-child { border-left: none; font-family:Verdana,sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;  font-size:10pt; background:#dcdcdc; background-color:#dcdcdc; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("</style>");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<img alt="" src=""cid:1022_03"" width=""817"" height=""123"" />");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("<br/>");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<p class=""par"">Dear " + txtClient.Text.Trim() + ",</p>");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine("Details:");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("<br/>");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine("<table>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<tr><td style=""background-color:#dcdcdc; widht:350px;"" >Model: </td><td style=""widht:250px;""> " + lstModelType.SelectedValue.ToString() + " </td></tr>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<tr><td style=""background-color:#dcdcdc; widht:350px;"" >Serial No: </td><td style=""widht:250px;""> " + txtSerial.Text.Trim() + " </td></tr>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<tr><td style=""background-color:#dcdcdc; widht:350px;"" >IP Address: </td><td style=""widht:250px;""> " + txtIPAddress.Text.Trim() + " </td></tr>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<tr><td style=""background-color:#dcdcdc; widht:350px;"" >AD Sharename: </td><td style=""widht:250px;""> " + txtADSharename.Text.Trim() + " </td></tr>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<tr><td style=""background-color:#dcdcdc; widht:350px;"">Department: </td><td style=""widht:250px;""> " + txtDepartment.Text.Trim() + " </td></tr>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<tr><td style=""background-color:#dcdcdc; widht:350px;"">Colour: </td><td style=""widht:250px;""> " + lstColour.SelectedValue.ToString() + " </td></tr>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("</table>");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<p class=""par""><em>" + techString + "</em></p>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("<br/>");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<div class=""divStyle""> Regards, ");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("<br/>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(lstApprover.SelectedValue.ToString());
        stringBuilt.AppendLine("</div>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<img alt="" src=""cid:TonerSignature"" width=""300"" height=""70"" />");

        stringBuilt.AppendLine("<br/>");
        stringBuilt.AppendLine(@"<img alt="" src=""1022_11"" width=""815"" height=""54"" />");

        return stringBuilt.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Add mime type to your resources.

for ex : LinkedResource img1022_11 = new LinkedResource(img1022_11Path,MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);

you can add Jpg, Tiff, Gif images, for png files there is a workaround.

use this.

```
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(
                      new LinkedResource("../EmailTemplate/ContactDetails.png")
                      {
                          ContentId = "ContactDetails",
                          TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64,
                          ContentType = new ContentType("image/png")
                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of Server.MapPath use website path to get the images